# Size, Length conversion?

Tags: c++, matlab

(I know I ask a lot of questions about this!)

Basically, I'm trying to convert some code from Matlab to C++ and I've come across this:

```
n = sum(size(blocks)) - len;
```

Now I have calculated the sum of the vector, and I have the length, but I do not know what "size" does? Because in C++ .size() will return the size of the vector.

Any ideas? (Not asking for code)!

Comment: Tell me what the types of these things are.

Comment: What are? sum is the sum of the vector blocks, size i think is dimensions of the vector, and length is the length of the vector?

Comment: @Phorce The `length` function (which is not mentioned here) returns the size of the first non-singleton dimension.

Comment: @paddy This code comes from Matlab, where the [length function](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/length.html) returns: Length of vector or largest array dimension and _not_ size of first non-singleton dimension!

Comment: @GuntherStruyf Do you know if there is a way to get the dimensions of a vector (size in matlab), if the dimensions have not been set? Thanks

Comment: @Phorce You mean in C++? No, but it seems you'll get a nonsensical value since (you say it yourself), the dimension has not been set...
You should check what you're trying to do, instead of just copying/translating everything over imho

Comment: @GuntherStruyf Now I think about it, you have a point ha! I'm trying to remove blocks from a vector that contain in-sufficent energy or frequency.. I don't understand why the for loop starts from n = sum(size(blocks)) - len .. Surely, it could just go from the length of the vector, check through each of the of blocks inside the 2D array and matches them against the criteria.. Thoughts?

Comment: @Phorce I don't have my crystal ball with me so I don't really know what you're talking about + my C++ knowledge is minimal

Answer (score 2):

In MatLab, `size` returns a vector of all the dimensions of a vector (or matrix).  So if `blocks` is a 4x2 matrix, then `sum(size(blocks))` will return `6`.  If the number of dimensions is 2 or less, the result always contains 2 elements.  *ie* a column-vector of length 5 would return `[5 1]` and a row-vector the same length would return `[1 5]`.

It's a bit odd to see `sum(size(?))`.  Often you see `prod` instead of `sum`, which multiplies all the dimensions together.

Anyway, hope that answers your question to satisfaction =)

Comment: I have, 600 elements inside a 2D array and each of the blocks in that array is of length 1. So what would be the result? arghh aha @paddy

Comment: Do you mean `blocks` is a cell-array?

Comment: I believe so.. Basically a 2D vector storing 1D vectors that contain 1 value.. If that makes sense?

Comment: What are the dimensions of your 2D array (or possibly matrix)?  If you are converting this code, all you need to do is add together the X- and Y- dimensions of your 2D array (and then subtract whatever `len` is.

Comment: Hey, all I know is that the size of the vector is 600. I dynamically set it, I don't set a W+H. Is there a STL function in C++ to get the dimensions? Thanks

Comment: @Phorce A vector in C++ is 1-dimensional.  The `size` member function returns the number of elements contained in the vector.  What is the value of `len`?  Is it by any chance `length(blocks)`?  If `blocks` is a 600x1 array in MATLAB, then `sum(size(blocks))` is of course 601.  I gather that you don't have access to MATLAB to actually try this code out.

Answer (score 1):

```
d = size(X) return the sizes of each dimension of array X in a vector d.
```

Lest say you have `d = size(rand(2,3,4))` then this would return d = 2 3 4 . Basically it gives you the size of each block in that array